# How to make a custom listview with one image and one textbox in windows7 phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i need to make a custom listview in windows7 phone. In this listview, i need to show one image  with one textbox. This listview will be dynamic. i will insert value in database and this listview will be generate till the last value of my database.
I am new in windows7 phone, any suggestion will be appricated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<ListBox>
```

The above code assumes you have bound a list, or set the `ItemsSource`, to a list of objects that expose `Text` and `ImageSource` properties.

Comment: If you save your images into a storage, probably you need to look to `converters`. Because you need to convert from `Path to image` to `ImageSource` object that will be displayed